# Rotate to a set degree then reverse and repeat in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, animation, rotation

I'm making my first project in Unity, a simple game where touching objects adds points to the player's score.

I'd like the objects to have a pleasant back and forth swaying animation on the Z axis. Nodding to the right 30 degrees, then to the left 30 degrees, on and on.

Here's what I've got...

```
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,12)*Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This gives me a nice slow rotation. But I am clueless how to tell Unity to stop at +30 degrees, reverse to -30 degrees, rotate again to +30, stop and repeat, etc, etc.

I'd really appreciate any help. Maybe there is a thread like this that I was not able to find? I assume it will involve some kind of 'if then' function?

Answer (score 2):

> This gives me a nice slow rotation. But I am clueless how to tell
>   Unity to stop at +30 degrees, reverse to -30 degrees, rotate again to
>   +30, stop and repeat, etc, etc.

I suggest you to use [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that. There are several ways of course of doing that. The code could look more or less the following:

```
IEnumerator LoopRotation(float angle)
{
  float rot = 0f;
  float dir = 1f;
  while(true)
  {
    while(rot < angle)
    {
      float step = Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed;
      transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,12)*step * dir);
      yield return null;
    }
    rot= 0f;
    dir *= -1f;
  }
}

void Awake()
{
  StartCoroutine(LoopRotation(30f))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sine wave.

During the update method, get the elapsed total time and store that as a float. Feed it to a sine function and you'll end up with a value between -1 and 1 that oscillates between the two values; multiply it by thirty and you can rotate an object from -30 degrees to +30 degrees.

`float elapsed = Time.deltaTime;
float degrees = Mathf.Sin(elapsed) * 30.0f;`

That might move a little too quickly, however, so you could always create a new floating-point variable and just increment that slightly each frame. Then feed that to the sine function.

`Mathf.Sin(0) == 0.0; 
Mathf.Sin(90) == 1.0f;
Mathf.Sin(180) == 0.0f;
Mathf.Sin(270) == -1.0f;`

I'm unfamiliar with how rotations are defined in unity, but I'll give it a go.

`float sineTime = Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime);
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * sineTime * 30);`

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: As [Trevor once told me](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13136/vary-speed-of-enemy-smoothly/13139#comment18074_13139), I'll pass on: The Hermite basic interpolator `P(t) = 3t^2 - 2t^3` (for `0 <= t <= 1`) is often used because it's faster to calculate than the sine. (Interestingly, that comment of his was on *my* first answer, as this comment is to yours. Consider this your inheritance. :D)

Comment: Heheh, thanks very much. It just immediately jumped to mind, but I'm intrigued now, so I'll give it a go and try it out! :-)